# Disable cloning of nested submodules

Tags: git, git-submodules

Following is the project structure.

project 1
  --> project 2 (Submodule of project 1)
      ----> project 3 ( submodule of project 2)

When i clone project 1 i want ONLY THE PROJECT2 files to be cloned and NOT PROJECT 3

I used the below command but still the clone commands clones all the submodules upto project3

```
git clone <project1-repourl> --recursive --depth 1
```

Can any one please help me with the command as how i can clone submodules but avoid further recursive clone in that respective submodule ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A one liner for excluding the submodule during the cloning process would be :

```
git -c submodule."X".update=none clone --recursive <repository>
```

Replace X with your submodule name

Comment: git -c submodule.<project3>.update=none clone --recurse-submodules <project1url> --> this command still clones the project 3

Comment: My bad...this works..i was using incorrect name at X

Answer (score 1):

This might work. Not positive but try cloning without the recursive option.

```
git clone <project1-repourl> --depth 1
git submodule update --init PROJECT2
```